# Laravel sanitize middleware not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using a sanitizing package.
this package is for laravel and  sanitizes data for security and XSS attacks and has a helper function: clean($data)  , $data can be a string or array.

I build a middleware to purify data for every requet that is comming.

handle() function for  this middleware is:

```
    public function handle( $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request = clean( $request->all() );

        return $next( $request );
    }
```

this function cleans and purifies every data thai is comming to my app.

I know I'm making a big mistake and misunderstanding!

what I have done wrong?

Comment: What Framwork you are using?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: No Errors. Just not workin. It doe not Sanitize my incoming data. I tested this middlware is loaded to my controller by dd() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `clean()` function should return an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` because that's what the `$next` `Closure` needs to proceed. Perhaps your `clean()` function is returning a different type such as a string or an array.

Comment: clean() function does not know anything about Http/Request! Its just gives string or array of strings and returns purified version of them.(e.g. removing <script> tags and etc.). what should I do now?!

Comment: Look at where your `$request` variable is getting passed at. The `handle()` method is injected the `Illuminate\Http\Request` object which is the `$request` variable and then you modified the value of `$request` by giving it whatever is the return value of your `clean()` function and then you passed it onto the `$next` closure. The way I see it, that's entirely what's wrong.

Comment: You should consider using the `e()` function for sanitizing inputs upon displaying them. Or if you're using Blade templates on Laravel 5.1, display your data using double curly braces: `{{ $someData }}`.

Comment: Thank you @Sandyandi your answer helped. Edit your answer for other amateur developers!!  I digged! into Request class found `replace()` function. this function returns an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`. now I can modify comming data and pass it to this function like following:     `$request->replace(clean($request->all()));

  return $next($request);`

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes, you can do that. Ultimately, you need to pass a `Request` object to the `$next` closure to proceed.